# how can I add more type when type of parameter existed

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have problem when I want to extend more type when parameter is existed like this code below.

```js
const animalTalk = {
  talk: (name: 'dog' | 'cat') => { // This code not allow for update
    console.log(name)
  },
}
animalTalk.talk = (name ) => { // << I would like to extends more 'mouse' in 'name'
  if (name === 'mouse') {

  }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just declare the parameter of the second type explicitly:

```
const animalTalk = {
    talk: (name: 'dog' | 'cat') => { // This code not allow for update
        console.log(name)
    },
}
animalTalk.talk = (name: 'dog' | 'cat' | "mouse") => { 
    if (name === 'mouse') {

    }
}
```

If you don't want to duplicate the common part we can use a conditional type to extract the argument (in out case the first one, but you can create similar types for other positions)

```
type FirstArgument<T> = T extends (p: infer A)=> any? A : never;
animalTalk.talk = (name: FirstArgument<typeof animalTalk['talk']> | "mouse") => { 
    if (name === 'mouse') {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to extend the last parameter automatically. The code may be look like this:
animalTalk.talk = (name: <extends name> | cat) => {

Comment: @TriTomVLE added a version that does not duplicate the common part, but it's longer. There is no way to extend the type without redeclaring the common part in some way (either explicitly as I did in the first snippet or by extracting it as in the second snippet). Let me know how you feel about the solution :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks. You save my day